# What steps are needed to activate audio enhancements and beamforming using the default Windows audio driver on Win11?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

Win7 had something called Audioenhancements for Speakers and Microphones. Not all Enhancements are available for all devices. Most times there are only a few enhancements available. In Win11 those enhancements dont seem to be available at all.

I am using a thinkpad x380 with a microphone array. There is proprietary software which should be able to beamform but i would like to use the beamforming microsoft provides.

If i install the microphone with windows standard audio driver it isnt recognized as an array and i dont see any enhancements to activate.

What do i have to do to first change the stereomicrophone to a microphone array and secondly to make all the audio enhancements available. Especially beamforming, which is provided by microsoft.

I tried Installing the Standard audio driver. It worked but the microphone isnt recognized as an array and there are no enhancements available.

edit: here is a list of available enhancements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-signal-processing-modes

Comment: Did you try [this method](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-enhance-audio-windows-11/) for enabling Audio Enhancements for the microphone?

Comment: yes i tried that. doesnt work. it really seems like a registry hack would make it possible.